# Attempting to use LibVirt with QEMU on Ubuntu 22.04 without KVM

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

My understanding is that I can use LibVirt and QEMU on Ubuntu 22.04 without having to use KVM. In order to do this I'm using the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install qemu-system qemu-efi qemu-user qemu-utils libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu
sudo mkdir /home/foo && sudo useradd -d /home/foo nomad
sudo usermod -a -G kvm,libvirt-qemu,libvirt foo
sudo mkdir -p /home/foo/libvirt/images
sudo mkdir -p /home/foo/libvirt/isos
sudo chown :kvm /home/foo/libvirt/images
sudo rmdir /var/lib/libvirt/images
sudo ln -s /home/foo/libvirt/images /var/lib/libvirt/images
sudo ln -s /home/foo/libvirt/isos /var/lib/libvirt/isos
sudo mkdir -p /home/foo/.config/libvirt
sudo cp -rv /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf /home/nomad/.config/libvirt/
sudo chown foo: /home/foo/.config/libvirt/libvirt.conf
sed -i 's\#uri_default\uri_default\g' /home/foo/.config/libvirt/libvirt.conf
sed -i 's\#user = "root"\user = "foo"\g' /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
sed -i 's\#group = "root"\group = "libvirt-qemu"\g' /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
sudo systemctl start libvirtd
systemctl status libvirtd
```

The very last line in the script is giving me:

```
Nov 06 13:58:52 ip-172-31-28-212 dnsmasq-dhcp[750]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.122.2 -- 192.168.122.254, lease time 1h
Nov 06 13:58:52 ip-172-31-28-212 dnsmasq-dhcp[750]: DHCP, sockets bound exclusively to interface virbr0
Nov 06 13:58:52 ip-172-31-28-212 dnsmasq[750]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Nov 06 13:58:52 ip-172-31-28-212 dnsmasq[750]: using nameserver 127.0.0.53#53
Nov 06 13:58:52 ip-172-31-28-212 dnsmasq[750]: read /etc/hosts - 7 addresses
Nov 06 13:58:52 ip-172-31-28-212 dnsmasq[750]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
Nov 06 13:58:52 ip-172-31-28-212 dnsmasq-dhcp[750]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Nov 06 13:58:53 ip-172-31-28-212 libvirtd[546]: libvirt version: 8.0.0, package: 1ubuntu7.7 (Michal Maloszewski <michal.maloszewski@canonical.com> Fri, 04 Aug 2023 10:42:25 +0200)
Nov 06 13:58:53 ip-172-31-28-212 libvirtd[546]: hostname: ip-172-31-28-212
Nov 06 13:58:53 ip-172-31-28-212 libvirtd[546]: Unable to open /dev/kvm: No such file or directory
```

My question is, how can I use libvirtd such that it doesn't look for /dev/kvm.